# Sending UDP packet to everybody in a LAN?

Tags: java, networking, udp

Is there a way to send a UDP packet inside a LAN so that every machine receives it? (Of course no guarantees because its UDP).

Like, sending a request "Hello, anybody out there?" and then listening for a response?

I got no problem with sending and receiving, just want to know if there's a way other than trying out every IP address possible...

**Edit:** This is what I use at the moment:

```
...
multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket();
multicastSocket.setBroadcast(true);
broadcastGroup = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
// multicastSocket.joinGroup(broadcastGroup);
...
```

The last line of code is commented out because it throws an exception. Now I've read that sending a packet to 255.255.255.255 is "deprecated since years" and most likely won't work on many LANs. Also, I'm not sure if I even need a `MulticastSocket` for this or if a normal `DatagramSocket` would work as well. But anyway, what would be the preferred way to send a UDP broadcast nowadays?

Comment: 255.255.255.255 is not a valid multicast group address, and you don't join multicast groups to send to them, but to receive from them. You need to decide which it is that you're doing: broadcast or multicast. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: I always tend to go for the simplest possible solution. If you are on class C subnet, I would suggest simply sending unicast to all 253 other hosts on the same subnet. Heck, even for class B, why not? It's only around 65K destinations.

Comment: @wookie919 "Why not"? Because the router probably won't support it?

Comment: I just want to send a broadcast packet to every computer in a LAN. My solution works for this, but I can just replace Multicast with Datagram, can I? So for my problem, I don't need to care about multicasts at all, since I only want to SEND, right? Okay, so I just replace the socket and it's "fixed".
However: What's the preferred way for broadcasting nowadays? I heard that IPv6 doesn't support broadcasting at all? Could that become a problem?

Comment: @EJP:A router that can't support 65K unicast packets? I think you misunderstood me. AyCe: The problem with broadcast/multicast is that it relies on the router/switch to do the work for you. Basically what you are doing is injecting a single packet into the network and relying on the network to duplicate the packet for every available host. If you have control over the network, then sending UDP over IP with broadcast destination address is fine. If not, again, what's wrong with sending unicast to all IP addresses? At least this method is guaranteed to work in any network.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm just wondering how, for example, all these games do it where you just have to look on a LAN-lobby screen. It's not so important for it to work on any network, and the MulticastSocket + 255.255.255.255 method DID work, at least for 3 computers. Now I've changed the socket to a DatagramSocket and it doesn't seem to work anymore, but I need to conduct further tests to be sure of that (because I tested it with a 4th, different computer). I'm also currently attempting to implement real multicast groups. Still don't quite like the idea of sending 65k individual packets :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found it out by myself:

Just open a `MulticastSocket` and use `joinGroup` on any IP between 224.0.0.0 and 239.255.255.255. Of course everything related to that multicast group needs to receive on the same multicast IP.
I did it for sending AND receiving, however, I think you only need it when receiving messages. When you want to broadcast a packet to everybody in the IP group, just send it to the IP you selected.

You should also do `setBroadcast(true);` to allow broadcasting for certain (?) systems.

Comment: If you had 3 hosts on the group, would they all join group 241.3.3.7 for example? Then one host wouls send a packet to 241.3.3.7 and it would arrive on all hosts listening on 241.3.3.7?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Exactly, except that 241.*.*.* is not within the supported range.

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking you actually need to broadcast the message. Basically you need [MulticastSocket](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html), this kind of socket is used on the client-side to listen for packets that the server broadcasts to multiple clients.

Here is the java tutorial to help you achieve that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: I'm using new MulticastSocket(); right now with setBroadcast(true);. Since I don't want to receive but just send messages, this seems to work, for the target address I use InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"); all apps listening on the port I send it to receive it. multicastSocket.joinGroup(addr); throws an Exception but it works without as well...

Comment: Answer is incorrect. `MulticastSocket` is not necessary when broadcasting. It is for, err, multicasting. Again, they aren't the same thing. The link you cite is incorrectly worded: it is about multicasting, not broadcasting. I've reported the error.